# "Politifact was unable to find that report, and neither were we."

Tags: grammaticality, parallelism

> Politifact was unable to find that report, and neither were we.

Is this correct? Shouldn't "were" be "could"?

Comment: It is idiomatic.

Comment: You made a leap by paralleling "was unable" with "neither could". Did you not think of paralleling "was unable" with "neither was/were {able}" ?

Answer (score 4):

I think there's nothing wrong with using "**were**". It's proper parallelism. It will make sense once you split the simplified sentence this way :

> Politifact **was** unable to find that report - (Third person singular, past)
>
> We (too) **were** unable to find it  - (First person plural, past)

**Update**:

Thanks to [Brian Donovan](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/76878/brian-donovan) for the wonderful point.

the prefix **un-** (in unable to)and **neither**, both being negatives,  aren't coordinated very well. Thus the sentence should either read:

> Politifact was ***unable*** to find that report, and ***so were*** we.

or

> Politifact was ***not*** able to find that report, and ***neither*** were we.

**"could"** might have been appropriate if the sentence were to read:

> Politifact ***could not*** find that report. Neither ***could*** we.

Comment: Example looks good but this answer fails to speak to the real problem, which is that the prefix *un-* is not the right sort of negative to coordinate with *neither:* OP's statement should be corrected either to *Politifact was unable to find that report, and* ***so*** *were we,* or to *Politifact was* ***not*** *able to find that report, and neither were we.* (This would be an answer if I could track down authoritative confirmation of the relevant rule.)

Comment: @BrianDonovan - I was pondering about the same point. Thanks for the clarification. I have added your points to the answer(quoting you). Wish you a Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: You need a space after report in the last quote.

Comment: I think the "so were we" version is very poorly constructed.  I far prefer the original.

Answer (score 1):

> Politifact was unable to find that report, and neither were we.

This can be rewritten as "Politifact was not able to find that report" and "Neither were we able to find that report".

The literate native-English-speaking mind will perform that mapping implicitly, and so the sentence will make sense and (as mapped) be syntactically and semantically correct.

Answer (score 0):

With this type of question, I think it can help to simplify a sentence as much as possible. Let's remove the clutter and break down the sentence into its most basic form:

> Politifact was unable.

So, your recommended sentence does not make sense:

> Politifact was unable and neither could we.

"Could" refers to "find," but "find" is not the main verb in the sentence. "Be" is the main verb in the first sentence, so "be" should be the main verb in the second sentence.

> Politifact was unable and neither were we.

The real issue with this sentence is the inclusion of "neither." "Neither" makes the sentence unnecessarily confusing. A good copy editor would have written the sentence like so:

> Politifact was unable [to find that report], and so were we.

Or:

> Politifact was not able [to find that report], and neither were we.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine as is (but your version with "could" is also okay).  The example

> Politifact was unable to find that report, and neither were we.

is from

> not ( Politifact was able to find that report ) and also not ( we were able to find that report )

The second "able to find the report" is deleted under identity with the first instance of it.  The "also" is moved down within the scope of the second "not" and it changes to "either".  At this point, the second clause could come out as "... and we weren't either".

The "not" of the first clause is realized as the prefix "un-" and the "not" of the second clause is realized as "n-":

> Politico was unable to find the report, and neither we were.

Finally, the "neither" causes inversion of the following subject and auxiliary.